# Keepass different privileges

Tags: user-accounts, privileges, keepass

Is there a possibility in Keepass to have multiuser access to a kdbx file with different access privileges?

Basically each group of users would have their own password to acess the database and there would be one masterpassword to access all passwords (the entire database).

I could not find that option in the settings menu.

Alternatively having a kdbx file for each group would work too if Keepass could load kdbx files in a cascade. Loading the first file with the masterpassword and getting the password for the next file out of the first database, etc.

Is there any fix for this problem? Does Keepass support different access level / multiple access-passwords ?

Answer (score 0):

On the [Keepass plugins and extensions page](http://keepass.info/plugins.html) there is a third party plugin called [KeeAutoExec](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#keeautoexec) that does cascaded loading.
It allows to automatically open additional databases when opening a database

Answer (score 0):

The solution you want would use client side security which is never a good idea.

A better approach would be to trigger an export on save on the database master's PC, which would export the database to another file, filtered by group or tag.

So one database would include only basic passwords, like for a printer or the guest share.
Another one would be for the IT support.[image: Keepass Action]